# Python+Django - can't see my product image, name and price when I do those changes :

Tags: python, django, e-commerce

I have this code

```
<div style="flex:2"><img class="row-image" src="{% static 'images/placeholder.png' %}"></div>
            <div style="flex:2">Product 1</div>
            <div style="flex:1">$20</div>
            <div style="flex:1">
                <p class="quantity">2</p>
```

and made those changes :

```
static 'images/placeholder.png' to {{item.product.imageURL}}
Product 1 to {{item.product.name}}
$20 to ${{item.product.price|floatformat:2}}
2 to {{item.quantity}}
```

[views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjtfB.png)

[models](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r14Wg.png)

Comment: It's very hard to tell where is the problem without seeing your views.py and models.py. Can you please post that?

Comment: @Jeet it doesn't let me to post them !

Comment: you can post the content of these files like you did with template.

Comment: @Jeet hey bro added the links with images of both !

Comment: What is your template name? I want to know which url you are hitting.

Comment: my template name is store with cart.html, checkout.html,main.html and store.html

Comment: I made the same changes in store.html and everything appears but when I do the change in cart.html they don't show !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo in your model `OrderItem` field prouct. Please fix it or do this change in your template `cart.html`

```
{% for item in items %}
<div style="flex:2"><img class="row-image" src="{{item.prouct.imageURL}}"></div>
<div style="flex:2">{{item.prouct.name}}</div>
<div style="flex:1">${{item.prouct.price|floatformat:2}}</div>
<div style="flex:1">
    <p class="quantity">{{item.quantity}}</p>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I will try now !

Comment: bro it works but with prouct! if I change to product it gives me an error! should I leave to prouct or what to do to change to product but without errors ?!

Comment: rename `prouct` to `product`, make migrations and apply them.

Comment: thank you so much bro! evertyhing is ok now, thank you again...u have paypal or whatever online money service ?

Comment: No worries, just follow me on [LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/in/chandrajeet-choudhary/) :)